# Which binding in WCF provides both streaming and session?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am using wsHTTPBinding with wcf session but it doesnt support streaming, if I use basicHTTP for streaming it doesnt support wcf session? Is there any solution without using MTOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netTcpBinding supports both, but it doesn't generally work well over the internet (since it's not HTTP- firewalls are more problematic). It's a very stable and performant choice for internal applications, though.

A question to ask though, is what you need the session for? If it's just to correlate logical requests, there are much smaller hammers than WS-ReliableSession. Just use basicHttpBinding with a cookie, or (shudder) turn on ASP.NET compatibility mode and piggyback on those sessions.